# Poker game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object-oriented, playing-cards, dom

I am creating a Poker game using the follow hand precedence (winning hands in descending order):

[image: RULES IMAGE]

So if the player enters 5 cards:

> TH JH QH KH AH

(i.e. 10**Heart** Jack**Heart** Queen**Heart** King**Heart** Ace**Heart**)

It will give the result:

> Royal Flush

It works fine at the moment, but being new to programming I was wondering if you can help me with better logic or any suggestions to improve my code.

[jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mubi/cngeqo9s/)

```
var Result = { "win": 1, "loss": 2, "tie": 3 };

var PokerHand = function(hand) {
    this.hand = hand;
    this.breakdown = {
        'numberCount': Helper.numberCount(hand),
        'consecutiveNumbers': Helper.consecutiveNumbersCheck(hand),
        'sameSuits': Helper.sameSuitsCheck(hand),
        'highCardIndex': pokerSymbols.indexOf(Helper.getHighCard(hand))
    };
};


PokerHand.prototype.compareWith = function(hand) {

    // No parameter given in function
    if(hand === undefined) {
        console.log('Please compare to another hand');
    }

    const player1 = new PokerHand(this.hand);
    const player2 = hand;

    // Get index of result in ranks (lower score better)
    const p1Result = ranks.indexOf(Helper.getResult(player1));
    const p2Result = ranks.indexOf(Helper.getResult(player2));

    // If both players only have high card, compare cards
    if(p1Result === 9 && p2Result === 9) {
        if(player1.breakdown.highCardIndex > player2.breakdown.highCardIndex) {
            message = 'You are the Winner! High card';
            return Result.win;
        } else if(player1.breakdown.highCardIndex < player2.breakdown.highCardIndex) {
            message = 'You Lost, BetterLuck next Time';
            return Result.loss;
        } else {
            message = 'Its a Tie !!';
            return Result.tie
        }

    // Else compare ranks index (lower score wins)
    } else if(p1Result < p2Result) {
        message = 'You are the Winner!';
        return Result.win;
    } else if (p1Result > p2Result) {
        message = 'You Lost, BetterLuck next Time';
        return Result.loss;
    } else if (p1Result === p2Result) {
        message = 'Its a Tie !!';
        return Result.tie
    } else {
        message = "Error Occured Please try again";
        return;
    }
};




const pokerSymbols = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K',];

const ranks = [
    'Royal flush',
    'Straight flush',
    'Four of a kind',
    'Full house',
    'Flush',
    'Straight',
    'Three of a kind',
    'Two pairs',
    'Pair',
    'High card',
]

var Helper = {
    numberCount: (hand)  => {
        let cardDenoms = {};

        cardNumbers.getHandDenominations(hand.split(" ")).map(ele => {
            if (pokerSymbols.includes(ele)) {
                typeof cardDenoms[ele] === "undefined"
                    ? (cardDenoms[ele] = 1)
                    : cardDenoms[ele]++;
            }
        });
        return cardDenoms;
    },

    consecutiveNumbersCheck: (hand)  => {
        let indexes = [];
        let consecutiveNumbers = true;

        cardNumbers.getHandDenominations(hand.split(" ")).map(ele => {
            indexes.push(pokerSymbols.indexOf(ele));
        });

        const sortedIndexes = indexes.sort((a, b) => a - b);

        for (let i = 1; i < sortedIndexes.length; i++) {
            if (sortedIndexes[i - 1] != sortedIndexes[i] - 1) {
                consecutiveNumbers = false;
            }
        }
        return consecutiveNumbers;
    },

    sameSuitsCheck: (hand) => {
        const suitsInHand = cardNumbers.getHandSuits(hand.split(" "));
        const suit = suitsInHand.shift();
        let count = 0;

        suitsInHand.map(ele => {
            if (ele === suit) {
                count++;
            }
        });

        return count === 4 ? true : false;
    },
    getHighCard: (hand) => {
        let highIndex = 0;

        cardNumbers.getHandDenominations(hand.split(" ")).map(ele => {
            if (pokerSymbols.indexOf(ele) > highIndex) {
                highIndex = pokerSymbols.indexOf(ele);
            }
        });

        return pokerSymbols[highIndex];
    },
    getResult: (hand) => {
        const denoms = cardNumbers.getHandDenominations(hand.hand.split(" "));

        // Royal flush         A => 10 same suit
        if (
            denoms.includes("A") &&
            hand.breakdown.consecutiveNumbers &&
            hand.breakdown.sameSuits
        ) {
            return ranks[0];
        }

        // Straight flush      5 consecutive numbers same suit
        if (hand.breakdown.consecutiveNumbers && hand.breakdown.sameSuits) {
            return ranks[1];
        }

        // Four of a kind      Four cards the same
        let duplicates = [];

        for (const prop in hand.breakdown.numberCount) {
            if (hand.breakdown.numberCount[prop] === 4) {
                return ranks[2];
            } else {
                duplicates.push(hand.breakdown.numberCount[prop]);
            }
        }

        // Full house          3 cards same denomination + a pair
        if (
            (duplicates[0] === 3 && duplicates[1] === 2) ||
            (duplicates[1] === 3 && duplicates[0] === 2)
        ) {
            return ranks[3];
        }

        // Flush               5 cards same suit
        if (hand.breakdown.sameSuits) {
            return ranks[4];
        }

        // Straight            Any 5 cards in sequence
        if (hand.breakdown.consecutiveNumbers) {
            return ranks[5];
        }

        // Three of a kind     3 cards same denomination
        for (const prop in hand.breakdown.numberCount) {
            if (hand.breakdown.numberCount[prop] === 3) {
                return ranks[6];
            }
        }

        // Two pairs           2 sets of 2 cards same denomination
        // One Pair            2 cards same denomination
        let pairs = [];
        denoms.map((ele, i) => {
            if (denoms[i] === denoms[i + 1]) {
                pairs.push(denoms[i]);
            }
        });

        if (pairs.length === 2) {
            return ranks[7];
        } else if (pairs.length === 1) {
            return ranks[8];
        }

        // High card           Highest card if no other combination
        return ranks[9];
    }
};


/* HELPER FUNCTIONS */

var cardNumbers = {
    // Get card numbers contained in hand
getHandDenominations: (cards) => {
    return cards.map(ele => ele[0]).sort();
},

// Get suits contained in hand
getHandSuits: (cards) => {
    return cards.map(ele => ele[1]).sort();
}

}




/* UI LOGIC */

let message;
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');


submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => { 

    let messageText = document.getElementById('message');
    let playerOneResult = document.getElementById('playerResult');
    let playerTwoResult = document.getElementById('oppoResult');   
    let playerOneHand, playerTwoHand, playerOneValue, playerTwoValue;

    playerOneValue = document.getElementById('player1').value.toUpperCase();
    playerTwoValue = document.getElementById('player2').value.toUpperCase();

    if (playerOneValue.length !== 0 && playerTwoValue.length !== 0) {
    playerOneHand = new PokerHand(playerOneValue);
    playerTwoHand = new PokerHand(playerTwoValue);

    playerOneResult.innerHTML = Helper.getResult(playerOneHand);
    playerTwoResult.innerHTML = Helper.getResult(playerTwoHand);

    playerOneHand.compareWith(playerTwoHand);

    messageText.innerHTML = message;
    } else {
            messageText.innerHTML = "Please enter valid Value";
    }

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### return value unused from `PokerHand.compareWith()`

The return value from the function to compare the hands doesn't appear to be used:

> ```
> playerOneHand.compareWith(playerTwoHand);
> ```

So why bother returning anything from that function (besides exiting the function early)?

#### Assignment of `message` before returning a value

That function `PokerHand.compareWith()` has many cases where a string literal is assigned to `message` (with scope beyond the function) followed by a `return` statement. This seems unorganized. Why not merely return the result (I would suggest adding an additional *tie* case, for the scenario where player2 has the high card). That way, the message can be set in the click handler (or another function), so that `compareWith` isn't responsible for checking the result and setting the mesage (refer to the [Single Responsibility principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html)). That way, the messages can be set in one place (instead of repeated, as they are in both cases) - adheres to the [Don't repeat yourself principle](http://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/).

To change this, the case `winHigh` could be added to the result set:

```
const Result = {
    "winHigh": 0,
    "win": 1,
    "loss": 2,
    "tie": 3
};
```

and the messages could be stored in a mapping (i.e. an array), with the index (starting at 0) of each message corresponding to the result :

```
const messages = [
  "You are the Winner! High card", //0 == "winHigh"
  "You are the Winner!",           //1 == "win"
  "You Lost, BetterLuck next Time",//2 == "loss"
  "Its a Tie !!"                   //3 == "tie"
];
```

Then take the result of calling `compareWith()` and check if that result corresponds to a key in `messages` - if so, set the message to that message; otherwise set it to the error message.

```
const result = playerOneHand.compareWith(playerTwoHand);
if (result in messages) {//.hasOwnProperty(result)) {
  message = messages[result];
} else {
  message = "Error Occured Please try again";
}
```

See this in action in [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aelliott/1uL9f6ew/3/). Instead of using an array for the messages, an object (i.e. a Plain-old JavaScript object - POJO) could be used, with the key of each message corresponding to the result:

```
const messages2 = {
    0: "You are the Winner! High card", //0 == "winHigh"
    1: "You are the Winner!",           //1 == "win"
    2: "You Lost, BetterLuck next Time",//2 == "loss"
    3: "Its a Tie !!"                   //3 == "tie"
};
```

And then check for the key using `Object.hasOwnProperty()`:

```
const result = playerOneHand.compareWith(playerTwoHand);
if (messages.hasOwnProperty(result)) {
    message = messages[result];
}
```

#### Cache DOM references

There are lines like below, which occur during the click handler:

```
let playerOneResult = document.getElementById('playerResult');
let playerTwoResult = document.getElementById('oppoResult');
```

Those assignments can occur outside the click handler (optionally in a DOM-ready callback) - and [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) can be used since the value shouldn't change within the lifetime of the page.

#### Use `filter()` for pairs

Instead of `map()` with a conditional:

> ```
> let pairs = [];
>     denoms.map((ele, i) => {
>         if (denoms[i] === denoms[i + 1]) {
>             pairs.push(denoms[i]);
>         }
>     });
> ```

you can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the pairs:

```
const pairs = denoms.filter((ele, i) => denoms[i] === denoms[i + 1]);
```

#### Classes

Since you are using keywords like `let` and arrow functions it appears you are coding for EcmaScript 2015, and this could use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). While only really syntactic sugar over the prototype syntax, they can streamline some things...

Comment: I have updated the answer to explain a possible way of doing that.

Answer (score 3):

To compare two poker hands, you can just compute their *rank* individually and then compare the ranks. This makes comparing very easy.

To compute the rank of a hand, first classify it to one of the rows in the picture you posted. The result of this classification could look like:

- royalflush ace
- royalflush 5
- pair 5, kickers ace jack 4 (note that the kickers are sorted already)
- highcard ace, kickers queen 10 7 3

These results can be written as lists of numbers:

- 10, 14 (the 10 means royal flush, the 14 means ace)
- 10, 5
- 2, 5, 14, 11, 4
- 1, 14, 12, 10, 7, 3

To compare these lists, just compare their elements pairwise.

Alternatively, you can also encode the complete hand as a single number. Each of the above numbers is less than 100, so you can write the numbers like this:

- 10 14 00 00 00 00 = 101400000000
- 10 05 00 00 00 00
- +2 05 14 11 04 00
- +1 14 12 10 07 03

And these are trivial to compare.

By organizing your code like this, there is only one function you have to test thoroughly, namely the computation of the rank. This makes the code much shorter.

Comment: Is it possible to guide me through a working example as a new programmer its really hard to understand and build the logic , sorry about that